# Write JSON from textfields to a file for iOS 5+

Tags: ios, json

I'm new to iOS programming, and having trouble finding a beginner-level explanation of how to write the contents of multiple text fields to a local json file in such a way to keep everything organized.

For example, a user form would have Name, Address, Email, etc., which would need to be put into a Customer object.

The purpose of this is to save data from several forms, and eventually pass that data to a database.

Comment: Why is that you want to store a JSON string in a file (if you let me ask)?

Comment: I need to save data in such a way as to be able to throw it at a database later (which I can do); I've updated my question to reflect that scope -- sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Generally speaking, put everything in an NSDictionary, then convert that to JSON.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, and a good seed for googling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert your text fields into a dictionary (or dictionary of dictionaries). Once you have that done, you convert the dictionary into JSON data and save that:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myJSONDict options:0 error:&error];

if (jsonData != nil) {
    NSString *jsonFilePath = ...;
    BOOL status = [jsonData writeToFile:jsonFilePath atomically:YES];

    if (!status) {
        NSLog(@"Oh no!");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"My JSON wasn't valid: %@", error);
}
```

You just need to create the path and check the status.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:form.name.text forKey:@"name"]'
[dict setObject:form.address.text forKey:@"address"];
...
NSString* jsonString = [yourFavoriteJsonTool convertToJson:dict];
```